# I need to get the ID of the created channel, but I don’t know how to do it? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My bot creates a discord channel after receiving a certain message.content and I need to get its created channel ID in order to display it in a message.
My code:

```
client.on('message', message  =>{
    if(message.content === (prefix + 'report')) {
            message.guild.channels.create (`Репорт (${message.author.tag})`, {
                type: 'voice',
                permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: '861645891848110100',
                    deny: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                },
                {
                    id: message.author.id,
                    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'STREAM', 'SPEAK', 'CONNECT','USE_VAD'],
                    deny: ['PRIORITY_SPEAKER', 'MUTE_MEMBERS', 'DEAFEN_MEMBERS', 'MOVE_MEMBERS', 'CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE', 'MANAGE_ROLES', 'MANAGE_CHANNELS'],
                },
                {
                    id: moderRole,
                    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'STREAM', 'SPEAK', 'CONNECT', 'USE_VAD', 'PRIORITY_SPEAKER', 'MUTE_MEMBERS', 'DEAFEN_MEMBERS', 'MOVE_MEMBERS', 'MANAGE_ROLES', 'CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE'],
                    deny: ['MANAGE_CHANNELS'],
                },
            ],
                reason: `${message.author.tag} sended report`,
        })

        const msg1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Обращение успешно отправленно!`)
        .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>, просим вас зайти в канал <#$> и ждать пока вас переместят для разбирательств.`)
        
        message.reply(msg1)
        message.delete()
    }
})
```

**New changes**

Okay, I changed my code a little, now it looks like this:

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.content === (prefix + 'report')) {
            const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(
            message.guild.channels.create (`Репорт (${message.author.tag})`, {
                type: 'voice',
                permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: '861645891848110100',
                    deny: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                },
                {
                    id: message.author.id,
                    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'STREAM', 'SPEAK', 'CONNECT','USE_VAD'],
                    deny: ['PRIORITY_SPEAKER', 'MUTE_MEMBERS', 'DEAFEN_MEMBERS', 'MOVE_MEMBERS', 'CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE', 'MANAGE_ROLES', 'MANAGE_CHANNELS'],
                },
                {
                    id: moderRole,
                    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'STREAM', 'SPEAK', 'CONNECT', 'USE_VAD', 'PRIORITY_SPEAKER', 'MUTE_MEMBERS', 'DEAFEN_MEMBERS', 'MOVE_MEMBERS', 'MANAGE_ROLES', 'CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE'],
                    deny: ['MANAGE_CHANNELS'],
                },
            ],
                reason: `${message.author.tag} sended report`,
        }))
        const msg1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Обращение успешно отправленно!`)
        .setDescription(`<@${message.author.id}>, просим вас зайти в канал <#${channel.id}> и ждать пока вас переместят для разбирательств.`)

        message.reply(msg1)
        message.delete()
    }
})
```

But I am getting the following error after testing:

```
(node:1344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
name: Could not interpret "{}" as string.
    at RequestHandler.execute (a:\Wiki Cheats\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (a:\Wiki Cheats\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async GuildChannelManager.create (a:\Wiki Cheats\discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildChannelManager.js:112:18)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (a:\Wiki Cheats\discord bot\index.js:35:29)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1344) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to save the newly-created channel as a variable which you can then reference later.

```
const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(...)
```

Then, you can use `channel.id` in your embed or another message.

P.S. you have to change `client.on('message', message => {...})` to `client.on('message', async message => {...})` in order to use `await`, otherwise you'll have to use `.then()` with nested callbacks.